# Python: Tkinter only opening after keyboard interrupt

Tags: python, user-interface, random, tkinter

need some help with a revision program. The code I have written below only opens the tkinter box after I have stopped the program with a keyboard interrupt - Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#Imports moduals used
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

#Sets GUI
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("500x500")
gui.maxsize(width=500, height=500)
gui.minsize(width=500, height=500)



#Sets list of facts

facts = ['fact one', 'fact two', 'fact three', 'fact four', 'fact five']

#Defines random fact generator
def fun1():
    r = random.randrange(len(facts))
    lbl = Label(gui,text=facts[r]).pack()


#Checks time (5s) before each new fact displayed
while 1:
   fun1()
   time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should call `mainloop` function to make Tkinter event loop start.

If you need run code periodically, use [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) instead of infinite `while` loop.

```
...


def fun1():
    r = random.randrange(len(facts))
    lbl = Label(gui,text=facts[r]).pack()
    gui.after(5000, fun1)

gui.after(5000, fun1) # <--- Call `fun1` function after 5000 ms.
mainloop()
```